# Is there a way to compare values of Class objects using Comparator?

Tags: java, class, comparator

Cant we use Comparator for Custom Class or Structure. I was trying to use Student class as parameter for Comparator but seems it wont work. Any idea how to implement sorting over class objects with help of comparator.
Code :

```
import java.util.*;

class Student {
    
    int id;
    String name;
    int marks[] = new int[5];

    public Student(int id, String name, int marks[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.marks[i] = marks[i];
        }
    }
}

class MarksSort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        Student arr[] = new Student[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int id = sc.nextInt();
            String name = sc.next();
            int marks[] = new int[5];

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                marks[j] = sc.nextInt();
            arr[i] = new Student(id, name, marks);
        }

        int res[] = marksSort(n, arr);

        for (int j : res) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
    }

    static int[] marksSort(int n, Student arr[]) {
        int[] result = new int[n];
        
        Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Student> (){
            @Override public int compare(Student A, Student B){
                //will add sorting logic here
            }
        });
                
        return result;
    }}
```

I wanted to sort in this manner inside comparator.

1. Student whose sum of marks will be highest must come up the leaderboard.
2. Students whose total sum of marks are the same will be sorted alphabetically ascending by name.
3. In all other case student with lesser id will come before in the leaderboard

Error that I am getting :-

```
Compile Error


MarksSort.java:46: error: no suitable method found for sort(Student[],<anonymous Comparator<Student>>)
Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Student> (){
^
method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
(argument mismatch; Student[] cannot be converted to List<T#2>))
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
1 error
```

Comment: An array is not a `Collection`. You are most probably looking for [`Arrays::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: What if I store Array value in an ArrayList ? Will that help me use it up in Comparator?

Comment: The question is unclear. An `ArrayList` is a `List` and thus a `Collection`. If you try to use an `ArrayList<String[]>`, then this will not work. It should be an `ArrayList<String>`. --- `Arrays:sort` takes an array, as well as a `Comparator` as parameters (just like `Collections::sort` takes a `Collection` and a `Comparator`).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishPrasad, yes, you can use List<Student> to use Comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.sort` is for sorting collections; you have an array; you'd have to use `Arrays.sort`. Secondly, you can certainly use the convenience methods in comparator, which makes things a lot easier to write and more readable to boot:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator
  .comparingInt(Student::getMarkSum)
  .thenComparing(Student::getName)
  .thenComparingInt(Student::getId));
```

This does exactly what it says: The student with the lower mark is sorted earlier than students with later marks. To differentiate students with equal marks, their name is used; to differentiate students with both equal marks and equal names, id is used. If it's still the same then, the 2 are comparator-wise considered equal. What that means depends on the data structure. For array sorting, that means they will be left in arbitrary order. For e.g. `TreeSet`, it means no 2 students can be in the set if the comparator associated with the TreeSet says they are comparator-wise equal to each other.

NB: You will have to make the methods `getId`, `getMarkSum`, and `getName` in your Student class, but that all sounds like you should be doing so: Java programmers will generally make getters, so, when in rome, be like the romans. If you really don't want to, you're free to implement them in the sorter, using e.g. `s -> s.id` instead of `Student::getId`. The point is: You need to provide a function that turns a student object into an int  or object. `Student::getId` is java-ese for: Just invoke the getId() method to do so. `s -> s.id` would be java-ese for: Fetch the value of the `id` field. You can put code in there too:

```
s -> {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int mark : s.marks.length) sum += mark;
    return sum;
};
```

works as a parameter to the `thenComparingInt` method. However, it makes things more readable and easier to test if you just make a `getMarkSum` method in Student itself: That would be proper Object Oriented design.